# Showing that every finite measure on $(X,P(X))$ can be written as $\int_E f \,du$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that every finite measure on $(X,P(X))$, where $P(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$ has the form $v(E) = \int_E f \,du$ for a non-negative measurable function $f$ and where $u$ is the counting measure.

I think we must use the Radon-Nikodym theorem here. Firstly any finite measure $v$ on $(X,P(X))$ is $\sigma$-finite. Also $v$ is absolutely continous with respect to $u$ since if $u(E) = 0$ then $|E| = 0$ so $E = \emptyset$ and so $v(E) = v(\emptyset) = 0$ (because it is a measure). However, $u$ (the counting measure) is not necessarily $\sigma$-finite, i.e. if $X$ is uncountable. So I cannot use the Radon-Nikodym here.

Perhaps the question was meant to restrict $X$ to countable sets? Since then $u$ is $\sigma$-finite and then Radon-Nikodym applies to give the result.

**Was there a mistake in the question or can we show the statement (in the first paragraph) as is?**

The original question:
[image]

Comment: We've seen a failed attempt, already. In fact, I thought of a similar answer, but then, I realized there's a hole in it, a very big one. The info "there's a $\sigma$-additive measure on all of the power set" is crucial, here, but it's non-trivial. The reason is explained here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103583/finite-measure-on-the-power-set

Answer (score 0):

The question as asked is (probably) independent of the standard axioms of set theory.  Specifically, the existence of a counterexample is equivalent to the existence of a [real-valued measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable), a type of large cardinal.  Such a cardinal cannot be proved to exist in ZFC, but is generally believed to be consistent with ZFC (though this cannot be proved in ZFC, even assuming ZFC itself is consistent).